# GET запрос в MVC php

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

Делаю сайт на MVC-каркасе. 
.htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Вот router:

```
class Router
{

    private $routes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $routesPath = ROOT.'/config/routes.php';
        $this->routes = include($routesPath);
    }

// Return type

    private function getURI()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        return trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $uri = $this->getURI();

        foreach ($this->routes as $uriPattern => $path) {

            if(preg_match("~$uriPattern~", $uri)) {

                // Получаем внутренний путь из внешнего согласно правилу.
                $internalRoute = preg_replace("~$uriPattern~", $path, $uri);

                $segments = explode('/', $internalRoute);

                //Находим название Controller
                $controllerName = array_shift($segments).'Controller';
                $controllerName = ucfirst($controllerName);

                //Находим название action
                $actionName = 'action'.ucfirst((array_shift($segments)));

                //Передаем в переменную $parameters оставшиеся части адресной строки
                $parameters = $segments;
                $controllerFile = ROOT . '/controllers/' .$controllerName. '.php';
                if (file_exists($controllerFile)) {
                    include_once($controllerFile);
                }
                $controllerObject = new $controllerName;
                $result = call_user_func_array(array($controllerObject, $actionName), $parameters);
                if ($result != null) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Берет свои пути из routes.php:

```
<?php
return array(
    'admin/product/update/([0-9]+)' => 'adminProduct/update/$1',
    'admin/product/delete/([0-9]+)' => 'adminProduct/delete/$1',
    'admin/products/create' => 'adminProduct/create',
    'admin/products' => 'adminProduct/index',
    'admin' => 'admin/index',
    'login' => 'user/login',

    'product/([\w]{1,})' => 'product/view/$1',
    'category/([\w]{1,})' => 'site/category/$1',
    '([\s\S\w\W\d\D]{1,})' => 'site/error',
    '' => 'site/index/$1',
);
```

Вроде бы все уже готово, но возникла проблема: не работают GET-запросы. Вообще. Т.е. роутер распознает ссылку `site/?utm_sourse=vk` как `'([\s\S\w\W\d\D]{1,})' => 'site/error',` исходя из чего ни один GET-запрос не передается корректно. Вопрос - как это исправить? Видел предложение добавить в .htaccess `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]` но не помогло :(

Comment: наверное, про error надо последней поставить, если вы по первому совпадению переходите. И не очень понятно, почему не переходить на ошибку, просто если совпадения не было

Answer (score 1):

Думаю уже поздно, но все таки:
Добавьте в свой `.htaccess` следующие строки

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
<files config.base.ini>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</files>
<files errorlogs.log>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</files>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ :D
Да, за год я уже полностью пересел на ларавел и эта настройка уже отпала сама по себе)))